# Autocomplete search box like flipkart / OLX / Udaan has using Elasticsearch 7.3 in php application

Tags: php, elasticsearch, jquery-ui, autocomplete, elastic-stack

I want to design classified portal where I am using Elasticsearch 7.3 to store product data so I can get quick search results in the list and autocomplete. 
I want to get the result as flipkart or olx have. e.g. "fridge in A.c" or "Jeans for Men" "Jeans for Women" "Jeans in levis" like.
as per my study of elasticsearch, I have first created Index using Analyzer and set Mapper accordingly for fields. 
Below is my analyer and mapper snippet.

i am using PHP 5.6 with Elasticsearch 7.3 on ubuntu 16.03

Analyer and create index :

```
PUT testmitesh
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "english_poss_stemmer": {
                "type": "stemmer",
                "name": "possessive_english"
            },
         "edgeNGram_filter": {
               "type": "edgeNGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 25,
               "side" : "front",
               "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"]
            },
            "shingle": {
              "type": "shingle",
              "min_shingle_size": 2,
              "max_shingle_size": 5,
              "output_unigrams":false
          }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "edge_nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "trim",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "edgeNGram_filter",
                  "shingle",
                  "english_poss_stemmer"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "trim"
               ]
            },
            "keyword_analyzer": {
              "filter": ["lowercase", "english_poss_stemmer","trim"],
              "tokenizer": "keyword"
            },
            "standard_analyzer": {
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            },
            "starts_with": {
                  "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
                  "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
            }
         },
          "tokenizer" : {
              "edge_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                  "type" : "edgeNGram",
                  "min_gram" : "2",
                  "max_gram" : "25",
                  "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Mapping :

```
    POST testmitesh/_mapping
    {
  "properties":{
         "product_name":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "raw":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               },
               "keyword_analyzer":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               },
               "starts_with": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "starts_with",
                    "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                },
               "edge_nGram_analyzer":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "analyzer" : "whitespace_analyzer"
               }
            },
            "analyzer":"edge_nGram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard_analyzer"

         },
        "product_description":{
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard_analyzer",
            "fields": {
                "starts_with": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "starts_with",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard_analyzer"
                },
                "edge_nGram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "edge_nGram_analyzer"
                }
            }
          },
         "product_category_name":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "raw":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               },
              "starts_with": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "starts_with",
                  "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
              }
            },
            "analyzer":"edge_nGram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard_analyzer"
         },
         "product_sub_category_name":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "raw":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            },
            "analyzer":"edge_nGram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard_analyzer"
         }
      }
   }
```

Here is my sample product json :

```
{
    "_index" : "testmitesh",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5d7b3752842ed900077ae5a5",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "product_name" : "samsung 275 l frost free double door refridgerator",
      "product_price" : 23790,
      "product_description" : "275 L : Good for families of 3-5 members\r\nDigital Inverter Compressor : Consumes lower electricity in comparison to a Normal compressor\r\n3 Star : For Energy savings up to 35%\r\nFrost Free : Auto fridge defrost to stop ice-build up",
      "product_fridge_brands" : "Samsung",
      "product_rating" : "3 star",
      "product_door_type_other" : "",
      "product_door_type" : "Double door",
     "product_working_condition" : "good",
      "product_about_delivery" : [
        "self delivery by seller"
      ],
      "product_extra_details" : "Bring home this 275 L double-door refrigerator from Samsung and increase the shelf life of all your ",
      "product_category_name" : "Electronics",
      "product_sub_category_name" : "Refridgerator",
      }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "testmitesh",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5d7b3fd9842ed900077ae5b0",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "product_name" : "lg 2 ton 3 star split dual inverter ac - black",
      "product_price" : 47999,
      "product_description" : "2 Ton : Great for large sized rooms (150-200 sq ft)\r\n3 Star BEE Rating 2018 : For energy savings upto 15% (compared to Non-Inverter 1 Star)\r\nAuto Restart: No need to manually reset the settings post power-cut\r\nCopper : Energy efficient, best in class cooling with easy maintenance.\r\nSleep Mode: Auto-adjusts the temperature to ensure comfort during your sleep",
      "product_a_c_brands" : "LG",
      "product_rating" : "4 star",
      "product_capacity" : "1.5",
      "product_inverter_technology" : "yes",
      "product_cooling_technology" : "Auto Air Swing",
      "product_how_old_it_is" : "1",
      "product_working_condition" : "excellent",
      "product_about_delivery" : [
        "self delivery by seller"
      ],
      "product_extra_details" : "KS-Q24ENXA, Copper Condenser",
      "product_category_name" : "Electronics",
      "product_sub_category_name" : "A.c",
       }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "testmitesh",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5d7b36e2842ed900077ae5a4",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "product_name" : "direct cool single door 3 star refrigerator ",
      "product_price" : 13456,
      "product_description" : "190 L : Good for couples and small families\r\nReciprocatory Compressor : Standard type of Compressor with Easy Maintenance\r\n3 Star : For Energy savings up to 35%\r\n\r\nWhirlpool presents this 190 L Direct Cool Single Door Refrigerator to keep your food fresh and beverages cold even during long hours of power cuts. This kitchen appliance features Whirlpool’s 6th Sense QuickChill Technology and Stabilizer-free Operation for effective and efficient cooling.",
      "product_fridge_brands" : "Whirlpool",
      "product_rating" : "5 star",
      "product_door_type_other" : "",
      "product_door_type" : "single door",
      "product_working_condition" : "excellent",
      "product_about_delivery" : [
        "self delivery by seller"
      ],
      "product_extra_details" : "Whirlpool presents this 190 L Direct Cool Single Door Refrigerator to keep your food fresh and bever",
      "product_category_name" : "Electronics",
      "product_sub_category_name" : "Refridgerator",
      }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "testmitesh",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "5d7b3809842ed900077ae5a6",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "product_name" : "haier hcf-175htq freezer chest",
      "product_price" : 29000,
      "product_description" : "1 Deep Freezer, 1 Basket, User Manual\r\nExcellent product and spacious. Best is it is a freezer also with a feature of refrigeration. So you can change temp from knob placed below outside the deepfreezer. Good for chilling beers.",
      "product_fridge_brands" : "Haier LG",
      "product_door_type" : "Side by side",
      "product_working_condition" : "poor",
      "product_about_delivery" : [
        "self delivery by seller"
      ],
      "product_extra_details" : "",
      "product_category_name" : "Electronics",
      "product_sub_category_name" : "Refridgerator",
      }
  }
```

Can someone guide me here pls? how can i achieve my requirements?
is there anything , i have to change in my analyzer ? how to initiate search query for autocomplete result as i mentioned above ?
so if in searchbox i type, 
'Fr' or 'fridge' or 'freeze' or 'frige' , i should get all result by fixing typo automatically and list out all results.

Comment: Add the query you have tried?

Comment: i dont know first that my analyzer and mapping is correct or not as per my requirement . and i am not getting how to create search query for this. so need help on this. 
i just got to know by Elasticsearch site document about , Term and phrase suggester with fuzzyness using to process search request but dont getting how to use as per my analyzer. @SathishkumarRakkiasamy

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example